# Объединение трёх словарей из цикла в один

Tags: python, циклы, словари

Имеются данные, которые выводятся из Exel при помощи цикла:

```
if cell_calendar_date == today_date and cell_working_hours_today in range (1, 25):
        d = {cell_last_name : cell_working_hours_today}
        print (d)
```

Соответственно выводит три словаря:

```
{worker1 : 8}
{worker2 : 5}
{worker5 : 8}
```

Как эти три словаря объеденить в один? Или как значения сразу выводить в один словарь?

Answer (score 0):

Вынести объявление словаря за цикл:

```
d = {}
for h in range (6, ws.max_column):
    cell_calendar_date = ws.cell(row=12, column=h).value 
    cell_working_hours_today = ws.cell(row=i, column=h).value 
    if cell_calendar_date == today_date and cell_working_hours_today in range (1, 25): 
        d[cell_last_name] = cell_working_hours_today
print(d)
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, выдаёт всё те же три разные словаря.

Comment: @siarhei полный код приведи, где есть тот самый цикл

Comment: for h in range (6, ws.max_column):
      cell_calendar_date = ws.cell(row=12, column=h).value
      cell_working_hours_today = ws.cell(row=i, column=h).value
      if cell_calendar_date == today_date and cell_working_hours_today in range (1, 25):
        d = {cell_last_name : cell_working_hours_today}
        print (d)

Comment: @siarhei исправил ответ